# how to remove 'Repositories you contribute to' in github mainpage

Tags: github

I have submitted an new issue to a repository. After that, a notification tab always appears in my github main page:

[image]

I just wan't to remove this annoying repository, but i can't figure it out...

Comment: Would be nice to be able to control that, wouldn't it? Hopefully someone will prove me wrong, but I'm pretty sure there isn't any way to clear it. Maybe if you contribute to a bunch of others it'll get pushed off the list...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/removing-yourself-from-a-collaborators-repository

Basically, go to Profile/Settings/Repositories and there will be a leave button against repositories you've collaborated on.

Comment: This does not remove the repo from the "Recent Repositories" list of the left side of the Github home page.  That's what OP is trying to achieve.  Sadly the only way to do this currently is to wait 4 months for it to remove itself.