# GitHub: How do I remove myself as a contributor of another person's repositories

Tags: github, repository

I want to remove a repository I was [added to as a collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) from my list of "Repositories" (found on the left on the main page at [GitHub](https://github.com) when logged in). But, I can't find a way to do that.

**Note:** My question is different from [how to remove 'Repositories Your Contribute To'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729042/how-to-remove-repositories-you-contribute-to-in-github-mainpage) -- he's trying to remove a repository that he's contributed to, I'm trying to remove a repository that someone else added me to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On the page at https://github.com/settings/repositories you should see a "Leave" button next to the repositories you have been invited to.

Additionnal information can be found on [the GitHub help pages for this topic](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/removing-yourself-from-a-collaborators-repository).

Comment: Looks like this is found by clicking on the icon/Gravatar for my profile (top-right corner), then 'Settings'.  On that page, in the left-hand column, click on 'Repositories' to get the link listed above.