# Github - remove repository from list on main page

Tags: github

On github's main page there is a list of repositories on the left. I got on this list repo "alanxz/rabbitmq-c". It is not forked. I'm not a contributor. It simply sits there. I suppose that it was added when I filled an issue there, but it was closed and I have no longer use for this repository.

When I go to Setting -> Your repositories, it isn't there. When I go to Personal settings -> Repositories, it isn't there. I have no way to remove it, I can't leave (as I'm not a contributor) and I can't remove it (as it isn't forked). The following questions are similar but do not apply or are identical but lack answers:

[GitHub: Remove a repository from "Your Repositories"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135579/github-remove-a-repository-from-your-repositories) (similiar, but that's not it)

[how to remove 'Repositories you contribute to' in github mainpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729042/how-to-remove-repositories-you-contribute-to-in-github-mainpage) (seems like exactly same problem, but no answers)

[Remove external github repository from https://github.com/ landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223797/remove-external-github-repository-from-https-github-com-landing-page) (no answers)

How can I remove this entry?

Comment: As far as I know you can only wait for it to fall off the end of the list or, if it's a private repo, have your access completely removed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is public repository. Oh, well, thanks for an answer, if waiting is the only way then so be it.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: @Vladimir Not exactly - after I worked with other repositories it simply "left the queue" - so you can say that it solved itself, but it took a lot of time and is quite annoying.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, that repository list sorts based on most recent activity. So, if you had recently contributed to that repo, it would be showing up there. That’s expected behavior.

The list does update automatically as you make new contributions to other repos. So, as long as you don’t make anymore contributions to the vuepress repo, you should see its name fall further down the “Respositories” list over time.

As for manually removing it, that isn’t currently possible. The dashboard view where you see that “Repositories” list is only viewable to you, and again, the list is sorted automatically based on recent activity. That all said, I can understand why you may like to remove a recently contributed to repository from that list.
Cheers!

Comment: So it seems that filling a bug report is also "contributing"? Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Per @SinisterDeveloper there does not seem to be a way to remove something from the list.

However, you may find things at the very top of the list that you were once interested in but not anymore.

If you select that project and then look on the upper right, if it is marked as "Watch" or "Unwatch", then click it and select "Ignore". It seems like that might cause it to gradually drop down the list and ultimately disappear since it will no longer be seeing activity from others contributing to the repository.

[image]

At least I hope this works ...